# Using Android Studio, how to display Day(mon,tue,wed etc.), Date, Month and Year from selected date in Datepicker

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

I am looking to create a simple code that will take a date from my datepicker and display each the day of the week, day, month and year in seperate textview.

Then to display the same for a day an input number of days later.

Example: Choose 12/02/2020 and enter 2

Output Wenesday, 12 02 2020
       Friday, 15 02 2020
I have the datepicker and the output to give myself output of the dates but i dont know how to get it to calculate the day of the week.

Comment: Please post your current code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") // Selected Date From Date Picker Format
    val resultFromDatePicker = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US)

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") // Convert Date To This Format
    val convertDateTo = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MM yyyy", Locale.US)

    // Result - Wednesday, 12 02 2020
    val result = ""+parseDate("12/02/2020", resultFromDatePicker, convertDateTo)

    // Parsing Date
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun parseDate(
        inputDateString: String?,
        inputDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat,
        outputDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat
    ): String? {
        val date: Date?
        var outputDateString: String? = null
        try {
            date = inputDateFormat.parse(inputDateString)
            outputDateString = outputDateFormat.format(date)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return outputDateString
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Calendar.toDayAndDateFormat(outputPattern: String = "EEE, d MMM yyyy"): String {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern, Locale.getDefault())
    return try {
        sdf.format(this.time)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        this.toString()
    }
}
```

now you can use with date like this:

```
val today = Calendar.getInstance()
today.toDayAndDateFormat()
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.